# Fragments are blank, but lifecycle is working properly

Tags: android, sockets, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager

I am working on the application, which inflates a complex UI element on **socket listener**. This same UI element is also inflated on a different **network callback** as well. This UI element includes tabLayout and viewPager (with 3 different fragments), I reuse the layout for both the use cases. this works perfectly when the network callback is triggered, but the when it is trigger via socket listener, the UI element is inflated, tabLayout is working properly, **but the fragment in the viewPager are blank**. I logged all the fragment lifecycle functions and it is running properly. but the fragment is blank.

Since the UI element is triggered in callbacks, but inflation of UI required UI Thread, hence I used runOnUiThread block and it works perfectly when network call backs are triggered, but it doesn't work on socket listener.

I also tried requestLayout() and disconnecting socket once required UI element is triggered so as to push changes on UI Thread, but it didn't work.

**Main Fragment**

```
// Views
var view1: View? = null
var v: View? = null
var inflater2: LayoutInflater? = null
lateinit val llvar: LinearLayout
lateinit val scroll: LinearLayout

override fun onCreateView(
inflater: LayoutInflater,
container: ViewGroup?,
savedInstanceState: Bundle? ): View? {

// Inflating the fragment
inflater2 = inflater
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)

// Initiating the views
llvar = v!!.findViewById(R.id.lllllayout)
scroll = v!!.findViewById(R.id.scrollview123)

// Fetching previous data
getPreviousData()

// Setting up the token string to the chatRoom
val topic = "ghostroom:$token"
val socketroom = socket.channel(topic)

socketroom.join()

// Listener of Socket on channel "Rivi Reply"
chatroom.on("mydataroom") {

     // Handling payload and converting into usable data
     val payload = it.payload
     val obj = JSONObject(payload)
     val suc = obj.getJSONArray("data")
     if(suc("type").equals(REQUIRED_DATA) {

           activity!!.runOnUiThread {

              inflateData()

          }

     }

}

// Returning the whole view "v"
return v

}


fun getPreviousData() {

    // Preparing the data for accessing the History API
    val data = JSONObject("""{"page_no":1""".trimMargin())

    // API base url
    val URL_ROOT = "https:SOME_URL"

    // API end ponit
    val login = "$URL_ROOT/END_POINT"

    // Volley request in action
    val stringRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(login, data,

        Response.Listener<JSONObject> { response ->

            try {

                // Fetching response from the listner
                val obj = response

                // Required data
                val suc = obj.getJSONArray("data")


                // Fetching JSONObject from the response data
                var e: JSONObject

                var messages = arrayListOf<JSONObject>()

                // Adding data to the chat screen
                for (i in 0 until suc.length()) {

                    // Fetching JSON Object from each response
                    e = suc.getJSONObject(i)

                    // Adding the messages to arrayList
                    messages.add(e)

                }

                activity!!.runOnUiThread {

                    page++

                    for(data in messages) {
                        if(data.getString("type").equals(REQUIRED_DATA) {

                            inflateData()

                       }

                    }

                }


            } catch (e: JSONException) {

                e.printStackTrace()

            }

        },

        Response.ErrorListener { volleyError ->

            try {

                val error = VolleyError(String(volleyError.networkResponse.data))

                Log.d("History API error", error)

                eof = 1

            } catch (e: Exception) {

            }
        }

    ) {


        @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
        override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {


            val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
            val token = "Bearer $headertoken"


            Log.d("Bearer", token)


            headers["Authorization"] = token
            headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"


            return headers


        }

    }

    //adding request to queue
    stringRequest.setShouldCache(false)
    VolleySingleton.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)

}


// Function to inflate and manage the getFlights of layout
private fun inflateData() {

    try {

        // Inflating flight card
        try {

            // Inflating flight card
            val dataCard = inflater2!!.inflate(R.layout.flight_card, llvar, false)
            val tabs = dataCard <TabLayout>(R.id.tabs_main2)
            val DataViewPager = dataCard.findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.viewpager_main2)
            val DataAdapter = GetDataAdapter(childFragmentManager)

            // Initiating the Adapter and viewPager
            DataViewPager.adapter = DataAdapter
            DataViewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 3
            tabs.setupWithViewPager(DataViewPager)


            // Adding tabSelectListener
            tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

                override fun onTabReselected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                }

                override fun onTabUnselected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                }

                override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                    DataViewPager.currentItem = tab.position
                }

            })

            // Adding the UI to layout
            llvar.addView(dataCard,0)

        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {

            // Logging error
            Log.e("Data Card error?", e.message)

        }

    } catch (e: Exception) {

        Log.e("Data block error", e.message)

    }

}
```

**GetDataAdapter**

```
class GetDataAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    return when (position) {

        0 -> {
            GetDataFragment1()
        }

        1 -> {
            GetDataFragment2()
        }

        else->{
            GetDataFragment3()
        }
    }
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return 3
}

override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
    return when (position) {
        0 -> "Chat"
        1 -> "Test"
        else -> {
            return "Trip"
        }
    }
}
```

}

**flight_card Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs_main2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    android:background="#F4F4F4"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:tabMode="fixed"/>

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager_main2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="310dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:background="@color/GreyForm"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should inflate and return layout in `onCreateView`

Comment: but I wan to inflate it only when I receive the data of required type from the socket. @RahulKhurana

Comment: What about inflate the layout inside `onCreateView` and set the parent container visibility to gone and when the data from socket is received set the parent container visibility to visible.

Comment: oh actually I want to inflate multiple elements and making the app dynamics will not be possible then @RahulKhurana

Comment: According to Fragment LifeCycle callbacks, you must return a view if you want to display within the fragment. Suggestion: Just Add a simple container `LinearLayout` etc and use it inside `onCreateView` method. Then when you receive the response from Socket then add Views dynamically into it.

Comment: Actually, I did that. llvar in the linearLayout in inside that I am inflating the required UI element. really sorry for the incomplete details, I have updated the code.

Comment: You're not returning view `v` inside `onCreateView`

Comment: so sorry, but I am returning it. @RahulKhurana

Comment: Now, What is the actual question or problem you're facing?

Comment: inflateData() in call form socket as well as from socket and volley response block, it is working fine when called from volley response block, but when called form socket, the fragments inflated inside the viewpager is blank, but the tabLayout is visible. I have added layout and viewPagerAdpater for more details, thanks in advance @RahulKhurana

Comment: then check your `GetDataFragment1()` `GetDataFragment2()` and `GetDataFragment3()` methods. Also, did you see title inside tabLayout?

Comment: GetDataFragment1() GetDataFragment2() and GetDataFragment3() is working since they are working fine when called from getPreviousData(), but not from socket. the title is visible and working properly, also 3 tabs are created, but everything inside in balnk white.

Comment: try to stop setting it from volley response block and set it only from socket

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: on it is still not working @RahulKhurana